# Поиск значения по ключу

Tags: c++, оптимизация, map

Задан массив пар a, b.
И другой массив С. Для каждого его элемента найти пару из первого, где С[i] = a,  вывести соответствующую b.

Пример:

Вход:

1 2 3 4 5 6 -1

1 2 3 -1

Выход:

2 0 4 -1

Для 1 есть пара 1 2

Для 2 пары не существует

Для 3 есть пара 3 4

```
map <int , int> myMap;
int a;
cin>>a;
while (a!=-1){

    cin>>myMap[a];
    cin>>a;
}

cin>>a;
while (a!=-1){
    cout<<myMap[a]<<" ";
    cin>>a;
}
cout<<-1;
```

Данное решение не проходит по времени.

Comment: Два вопроса: зачем нужно `cout<<-1;` и как получилось `2 0 4`?

Comment: Если уж даете олимпиадные задачи, то давайте и ссылку :) Ваше решение вообще не проходит - поскольку -1 во входных данных нет, цикл ввода вообще не завершится...

Comment: Данное решение не проходит ни по каким критериям

Comment: -1 это обозначения конца массивов.

Comment: делаю ставку на очень долгое чтение.

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать std::unordered_map. У std::map есть свойство отсортированности, которое усложняет определённые операции. У первого такого нет ограничения.